# My button is turning my text into a string when I need it to be an integer

Tags: javascript

He y'all.

I've been stuck on this button for the past 45 minutes or so and I can't seem to figure out exactly how to fix my problem. I created three buttons.

(html)

```
<div class="action">
            <button id="start" onclick="start()">Start</button>
            // I have not done the Stay function yet
            <button id="stay">Stay</button>
        </div>
    <div class="announce" id="afterStart">
        <p id="hit"></p>
```

(javascript)

```
function start() {
    let score = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 + 1);
    let scoreTotal = document.getElementById("score-total");
    scoreTotal.textContent = `Your score: ${score}`
```

The first part of the button grabs the button ID of my Start button. Doing so displays the text "Your Score" followed by a random number between 1 - 11.

```
let proceed = document.getElementById("hit");
    if (score < 21) {
        proceed.textContent = "Do you wish to use another card?"
        let hitButton = document.createElement("button");
        hitButton.innerHTML = "Hit";
```

This grabs the ID of the second div in my HTML and creates a new button, which displays the text "Hit". By clicking "Hit" it does the following function:

```
        hitButton.onclick = function () {
            let score = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 + 1);
            scoreTotal.textContent += score;
        }
```

And herein lies the problem. For example, if I click "Start" and randomly get the number 3, it'll display:

Your score: 3

But when I click Hit, if I randomly got the number 11, it would turn my score into 311, instead of adding 3 + 11 together. It's effectively turning my code into a string, and no matter what I do I can't seem to fix it. I've tried adding a + in front of various things, as well as using parseInt. Nothing seems to work. Here is the rest of my code.

```
        let myButton = document.getElementById("afterStart")
        myButton.appendChild(hitButton);
        document.getElementById("start").onclick = null;
```

This is just creating the Hit button below some text. After clicking "Start" I decided to disable the button.

```
    } else if (score === 21) {
        proceed.textContent = "You won!"
    } else {
        proceed.textContent = "You lose!"
    }
```

[And here is my function in full in case all the spaces is confusing.](https://pastebin.com/J8AkFpx0)

**What I'm basically asking is this.**

How can I get my "Hit" button to add to my total score as an integer instead of a string?

I'm attempting my second ever project: Blackjack! I've had a lot of success in my first project, which was a unit converter, but struggling a bit with this. I'm doing my best not to follow any tutorials or anything, as I've been in tutorial hell for months.

Comment: Maybe you should add those attempts at "adding a +" or "using parseInt", because the solution would use those

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

scoreTotal.textContent = parseInt(scoreTotal.textContent) + score;

You are making a string concatenation and you dont want it :)
You want 11 + 3 and not '11' + 3. .textContent returns a string.